# Retrieve MongoDB GridFS file using Ruby

Tags: ruby, mongodb, gridfs

I am trying to retrieve a binary file that I successfully stored using GridFS.
I am using MongoDB v3.0.6, Ruby 2.0.0 and MongoDB Ruby Driver v 2.0.1 on Mac OS X.

Is there a working example?

Answer (score 1):

Looking over the docs, it seems like this should work:

```
client = Mongo::Client.new([ '127.0.0.1:27017' ], :database => 'music')
client.database.fs.find_one(:filename => 'new-file.txt') #=> Returns a Mongo::Grid::File
```

Here's how to stream it to a file:

```
client.database.fs.open_download_stream(file_id) do |stream|
  IO.write('some-file', stream.read)
end
```

Comment: This returns a Mongo::Grid::File variable. I want to get the actual stored file. So far, I had no luck.

Comment: What do you mean 'get' it...?

Comment: Save the actual file.

Comment: It's already saved.  You can stream it to another file if you want?

Comment: How? I am looking for the Ruby code to do so (using MongoDB Ruby Driver v2.0.1).

Comment: The code you mentioned does not work for me; I get error messages when I run it.

Comment: gridFSretrieve.rb:18:in `block in <main>': undefined local variable or method `io' for main:Object (NameError)
     from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/mongo-2.1.1/lib/mongo/grid/fs_bucket.rb:212:in `block in open_download_stream'
     from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/mongo-2.1.1/lib/mongo/grid/fs_bucket.rb:210:in `tap'
     from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/mongo-2.1.1/lib/mongo/grid/fs_bucket.rb:210:in `open_download_stream'
     from gridFSretrieve.rb:17:in `<main>'

Comment: `require 'rubygems'`
`require 'mongo'`

`include Mongo`

`$client = Mongo::Client.new([ '127.0.0.1:27017' ], :database => 'garden')`
`Mongo::Logger.logger.level = ::Logger::ERROR`
`$files = $client[:files]`

`$file = $client.database.fs.find_one(:filename => 'aTextFile.txt')`

`$client.database.fs.open_download_stream($file) do |stream|`
`io.write(stream.read)`
`end`

`fs.download_to_stream($file, StringIO.new)`

Answer (score 0):

The following code works:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'mongo'
include Mongo

$client = Mongo::Client.new([ '127.0.0.1:27017' ], :database => 'garden')
Mongo::Logger.logger.level = ::Logger::ERROR
$files = $client[:files]

puts 'connected!'

# Upload file
fs = $client.database.fs 
$file = File.open("delete.rb")
$file_id = fs.upload_from_stream("delete.rb", $file)
$file.close

$file_to_write = File.open('perfectCopy', 'w')
fs.download_to_stream($file_id, $file_to_write)
```

Mihalis.